# Magento new user registration event on one page checkout

Tags: magento

I've built an observer that listens to the **registration_success_observer** event that is emitted upon new user registration (from the accounts page). The observer handles various functionality, most importantly upgrading the user to a *membership group* if a membership id is passed in.

The problem is that I need to have the same functionality for users who are checking out AND signing up as a new customer. I somehow need a way to figure out if they are signing up as a new customer (via event?) from the one page checkout screen, in addition to re-calculating the totals -- some items in our store have special pricing for groups.

Does anyone know the best way to go about this? Specific events that I should listen for, or any other code snippets for handling functionality within the one page checkout screen would be helpful.

** **Update** **

It just occurred to me that a customer isn't actually created until after the order is complete. Any workarounds for this?

Comment: You are correct with that the users are only created once the checkout has been completed.

Comment: @tech0925 any thoughts come to mind for a workaround?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could create your own 'custom event' using the logic below to check which method they use to check out on success.phtml or incorporate it in  `sales_order_place_before`

```
$quoteId = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId($this->getOrderId())->getQuoteId();
$quote = Mage::getModel('sales/quote')->load($quoteId);
$method = $quote->getCheckoutMethod(true);
if ($method == 'register'){
//the customer registered...do your stuff
}
```

Source : http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/273690/#t375160

But what your trying to do may not be possible without rewriting the onepage checkout, because a customer is created before order is store in the db but after processing the credit card so the amount the credit card is bill for wouldn't equal the order total.

You could try to add a third option to the first step in the checkout process ('register as a member') that allow them to create an account before start checking out.